# Getting a runtime error in Swift 4.2 for an existing Objective-C code

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is the error:

> -[UIApplication statusBarOrientation] must be used from a main thread only

statusBarOrientation is used in two places in my code.

1. ```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(positionHUD:) 
                         name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
                         object:nil];
   ```

This one is in Objective-C .m file ^^

2. ```
   UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarOrientation;
   ```

Please help with any clue or work around for this. Thanks!

Comment: post the context you use them in

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error is telling you to do?

Comment: `UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarOrientation` is _not_ being called on the main thread and it must be.

Comment: You have a thread violation - `statusBarOrientation` can only be called from within the context of the main thread.  You need to do some digging and find out how this method is been called and determine, if you can, which thread it's been called and make changes so that the call ends up in the main thread

Comment: to call a method in main thread, use the Grand Central Dispatch (GCD), google it up bruv.

Comment: Is the second code snippet coming from an Objective-C .m file too?? It doesn't look like Swift code...

Comment: @gog yes it is used in objective-C code. I tried below code and it's not working:

Comment: @gog dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            label.stringValue = result
        }
    }

Comment: @gog This is sample code ^^

Comment: @MadProgrammer This is the scenario where i'm using statusBarOrientation :  #if !defined(SV_APP_EXTENSIONS) && TARGET_OS_IOS
    self.frame = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].bounds;
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarOrientation;

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried objective-C NSoperational Queue code to run it on Main thread. It's not working. Please suggest any approach to run it on main thread.

Comment: @Sh_Khan There is the context mentioned above ^^

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that the problem is coming from (1); the error is likely coming from you reading the `statusBarOrientation` member from a thread other than the main one.

This is how you can read the `statusBarOrientation` from the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    // Now, we are in the context of the main (GUI) thread. You can perform any GUI updates here.
    self.frame = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].bounds;
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarOrientation;
    // Put any other code that makes use of the "orientation" variable inside here

});
```

From here on, it all depends on what you want to do with the `orientation` variable.